# How to set permissions so a user (Role) can Edit Content but not Change View

Tags: permissions, roles, 2sxc

I have a user in the Role "Content Manager". The Role "2sxc Designers" exists and the user is not in that role.

My hope or expectation was that they would be able to edit Content but not change the view. Am I missing something? What are the steps needed so that a Content Manager can edit the content but not see/use the the Change View option? I realize I can code it in the View (Razor), but this seems like a common use case, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this specific option would require that you use content-type or item permissions. So basically DNN would believe that the user doesn't have edit permissions, then you set the permissions you want on either the content-type (if a user is allowed to edit all BlogItems) or specific items (for example, if registered-users may create, and people who created may edit).

then in your template you would have to enable editing with Edit.Enable(). You'll need to google it a bit, but it's a common use case.